# java lang Null Pointerexception After update Google Service

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services

> When I added Library in my Project And Library has a Google service

1. Old plugin version is 4.1.0 of Google Service in my Library
2. Verify gradle can configure itself, project builds
3. Set plugin version to 4.2.0 of Google Service
4. The only visible message is `Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException`
5. Gradle Version is 3.3.1

*Please tell me what can I do in this situation ?*

**LogCat**

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
>
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warningsCONFIGURE FAILED in 11s
>
> ERROR: Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post your logat screen error

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: @PratikButani Gradle version is 3.3.1

Comment: Please post your build.gradle of `app-level` and `root-level`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*if you want to out from this error*

> so please backward of your google service version from 4.2.0 to 4.1.0 this is jugad not a solution
>
> Error is gone......:)